# How to handle multiple filters in SAS stored process

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I'm creating a SAS stored process report in which user can filter data using different cafeterias.

This is what I'm doing

```
%let ID_WHERE_CLAUSE=; 
%let Source = "group";
%let ActionRequired = "Daily";


%macro SetFilters;

data _null_; 

%if &&ActionRequired ne "A" %then %do;
%let test = "ActionR";
    call symputx('ID_WHERE_CLAUSE',cats(' and ActionRequired = ',' &ActionRequired',''));
%end;


%if &&Source ne "A" %then %do;
%let test = "Source";
    call symputx('ID_WHERE_CLAUSE',cats('and Source = ',' &Source',''));
%end;

run;

%mend; %SetFilters;

%put &ID_WHERE_CLAUSE;
```

in ID_WHERE_CLAUSE data should be as `and action required = "Daily" and source = "group"` but my code is only appending last filter to my `ID_WHERE_CLAUSE` variable as  `and source = "group"`

my **expected result** is  `and action required = "Daily" and source = "group"`

but **actual result** I'm getting is `and source = "group"`

That's why I'm not getting my expected result. How can I append all where conditions in my `ID_WHERE_CLAUSE` variable.

I tried this too but didn't work either.

```
call symputx('ID_WHERE_CLAUSE',' and ActionRequired =  &ActionRequired','');
call symputx('ID_WHERE_CLAUSE', ' and Source =  &Source');
```

I'm using it as

```
proc sql noprint;
create table filter_data as
select * from data 
where 1=1 &ID_WHERE_CLAUSE;
quit;
```

Kindly tell me how can i concatenate all where clause to it or any better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call symputx` does not append to macro variables - it overwrites them. So you need to capture the existing value as part of the new value you want to set. E.g.

```
call symputx('ID_WHERE_CLAUSE',cats(symget("ID_WHERE_CLAUSE"),'and Source = ',' &Source',''));
```

You need to use `symget` to do this in your scenario rather than referencing the macro variable directly, otherwise it may be resolved before your earlier data step executes and sets the initial value.